# SQL command from eclipse using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have been searching and trying different stuff for awhile, but have not found an answer. I'm trying to make a connection to sql using JDBC from eclipse. I am having trouble when I need to select a string in the database.  If I use:

```
Select name from data where title = 'mr';
```

That works with terminal/command line but when I try to use eclipse where I use

```
statement sp = connection.createstatement();
resultset rs = sp.executequery("select name from data where title = '" + "mr" + "'");
```

It does not give me anything while the terminal input does. What did I do wrong in the eclipse? Thanks

Heres a part of the code. Sorry, its a bit messy, been trying different things.

```
private boolean loginChecker(String cid, String password) throws SQLException{
        boolean check = false;
        PreparedStatement pstatment = null;     

        Statement stmt = null;
        //String query = "SELECT 'cat' FROM customer";
        String query = "select '"+cid+"' from customer where password = '"+password+"'";
        try {
            System.out.println("in try......");

            //stmt = con.createStatement();
            //ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

            //System.out.print(rs.getString("cid"));
            while(rs.next()){
                check = true;
                System.out.print(rs.getString("cid"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (stmt != null) { 
                //stmt.close(); 
            }
        }

        return check;
    }
```

Second try on a simpler query:

```
public List<Object> showTable() {
        List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        String name = "bob";
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement preStatement = con.prepareStatement("select total from test where name = ?");
            preStatement.setString(1, name);

            ResultSet rs1 = preStatement.executeQuery();

            while(rs1.next()){
                System.out.println("there");
                System.out.println(rs1.getInt("total"));
            }


        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            System.out.print("Message: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It is bad practice to use hardcoded literals for parameters whose value will change.  Go google about JDBC parameterized queries.  The issue has probably nothing to do with Eclipse.  That is just the IDE to compile/debug your app.

Comment: There could be lots of problems.  Are you getting any exceptions??

Comment: The 'mr' in the question was just for example. Its actually an input from method. There is no exception, it just comes up as false when i call rs.next();

Comment: It's better if you show us your actual code.

Comment: I added part of the code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not closing the `ResultSet` before you are trying to use it.  This can happen when you return a `ResultSet` and try to use it elsewhere.  If you want to return the data like this, use `CachedRowSet`:

```
   CachedRowSet crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
   crs.populate(ResultSet);
```

CachedRowSet is "special in that it can operate without being connected to its data source, that is, it is a disconnected RowSet object"

Edit: Saw you posted code so I thought I add some thoughts.  If that is your ACTUAL code than the reason you are not getting anything is because the query is probably not returning anything.

```
    String query = "select '"+cid+"' from customer where password = '"+password+"'";
```

This is wrong, for two reasons.  1) If you are using prepared statements you should replace all input with '?' so it should look like the following:

```
    String query = "select name from customer where password = ?";
```

Then:

```
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    prepStmt.setString(1, password);
    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
```

2)

```
    System.out.print(rs.getString("cid"));
```

Here are are trying to get the column named "cid", when it should be the name stored in cid.  You should actually never be letting the user decide what columns to get, this should be hardcoded in.

Comment: Ok, I see. I changed that code.  I actually didn't have to use prepared statement since I am not updating anything.  Instead, I am doing query and that still doesnt work.

Comment: You cannot use `?` place holders with column names. That won't work.

Comment: I did this test but it still doesn't work, if I have select name from test where total = ? ... it works but when I switch name with total it does not.  I have this in the database name varchar(20) and total (int).  See above for edit.

Comment: @user2185801 " I actually didn't have to use prepared statement since I am not updating anything" WRONG! You don't have to be updating anything for SQL injection to take place.  Anywhere there is user input for any reason there is a chance of injection.  (Always use prepared statements where there is user input.)  Back to answering, could be that `select name from test where total = ?` works because there is some row that equals what you are passing for total.  But `select total from test where name = ?` doesn't work because you are getting more specific and so there does not exist anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the column name.

```
String query = "select "+cid+" from customer where password = '"+password+"'";
```

You've not mentioned which database you're working with but many databases like Oracle change the column case to upper case unless they're quoted. So, you only quote table columns if that's how you had created them. For example, if you had created a table like

```
CREATE TABLE some_table ( 'DoNotChangeToUpperCase' VARCHAR2 );
```

Then you would have to select the column with quotes as well

```
SELECT 'DoNotChangeToUpperCase' FROM some_table
```

But, if you didn't create the table using quotes you shouldn't be using them with your SELECTs either.